# Getting null value in the foreign key field of my table in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

```
I have 2 tables in my application:
1.newuser
2.introducer_table

Newuser1 table contains *sid**(primary key,auto-generated field)****,  fathername,gender,datebirth,occupation,addharnumber as columns
```

1.I’m inserting values into the newuser table using java prepared statement like below:

```
PreparedStatement pst =  con.prepareStatement("insert into newuser1 (name,fathername,gender,datebirth,occupation,aadharNumber) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

          //pst.setString(1,NULL);
          pst.setString(1,”xyz”);
          pst.setString(2,"ram");
          pst.setString(3,"male");
          pst.setString(4,"oct25");
          pst.setString(5,"emps");
          pst.setString(6,"4564");
data is inserted successfully,but I want the sid value of newuser1 in my  introducer_table so I write the query like this in prepared statement to select the last   insert  id.

My introducer_table contains the columns: 

**sid(foreign key),name,accountno,sign**
PreparedStatement pst =  con.prepareStatement("insert into    introducer_table(sid,name,accountno,sign) values((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() from   dual),?,?,?)");

              //nomine details into data base
              //pst.setString(1,NULL);
              pst.setString(1,"ram");
              pst.setString(2,"8945");
              pst.setString(3,"ssss");

 When I execute this,Im getting ‘0’ value in the sid column of introducer_table.I make   sid column as not null while creating intoducer_table,even im getting the ‘zero’ value like this:
```

Introducer_table:

```
**Sid**   name   accountno     sign
**0**     ram      8945        ssss
```

**Please help me I was stucked by this problem from so many days.**

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it your way think about using

```
con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

and then after your insert

```
pst.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = prest.getGeneratedKeys();
```

```
int last_inserted_id = -1;
if(rs.next())
{
  last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: but i write the prepared statement code for inserting introducer_table in another java class can I use this generated key in  another class?It will work?

Comment: Yes, just use the value of `last_inserted_id` to set the value of `sid`

Comment: means to use this last_insert_id variable in my another class I must create obj for this class and can use it.Is it right?

Comment: You need somehow to pass this value from where you get it, to where you want to use it.  This maybe by the use of class variables or simply by local variables returned from a method.

Comment: hi im getting difficulty in sending the generated id can you give me sample code please, I must use this last_insert_id variable in another class

Comment: here is a hint `return last_insert_id;` If you have different problems then post a new question.